# div disappears when box-shadow is added when using Safari

Tags: css, safari

I am making a card using code based on [this article](https://tammyritterskamp.com/how-to-make-css-greeting-card/) and I noticed that when I add a box-shadow to `.card__panel--front`, the front of the card disappears on Safari, but I don't know why or how to fix it. It works fine on Firefox and Chrome (haven't tested on any other browsers so far).

If while in Safari, you inspect element and toggle the box-shadow on `.card__panel--front` you will see the card front appear and disappear.

Code is below, but [here is a jsfiddle as well](https://jsfiddle.net/ka8ycsdw/) (has scss)

```js
const openBtn = document.querySelector(".js-card-opener");

openBtn.onclick = function () {
  document.body.classList.toggle("open");
};
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
}

.card__container {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  perspective: 1400px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .open .card__container {
transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  }
}

.card {
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 600px;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 120vw;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(65deg);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.open .card {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.card__panel {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  backface-visibility: visible;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform-style: preserve-3D;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
}
.card__panel--front {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: #6288e6;
  z-index: 1;
  /*
  Add/remove this box shadow to see the front page
   appear and disappear in Safari 
  */
  box-shadow: black 10px 10px 10px;
}
.open .card__panel--front {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -170deg);
}
.card__panel--inside-left {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 0;
}
.open .card__panel--inside-left {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -170deg);
  box-shadow: black -10px 10px 10px;
}
.card__panel--inside-right {
  border-left: none;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
}
.open .card__panel--inside-right {
  box-shadow: black 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click card to open</p>

<div class="card__container js-card-opener">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__panel card__panel--front">
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card__panel card__panel--inside-left">
    </div>
    <div class="card__panel card__panel--inside-right">
      <p>Happy everything!</p>
      <p>Your friend, Tammy</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

EDIT: Updated to show different shadows for different parts of the card

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using on `&--front` class you should target the main `&__panel` to add shadow to the whole card. like

```
&__panel{
      box-shadow: black 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Ah my bad, in the simplification I did based on the original, I didn't translate that the `--inside-left` gets a different shadow (`box-shadow: black -10px 10px 10px;`) and both of them only get a shadow when `body` has the `.open` class. Otherwise it's too much shadow when closed, and in the wrong place when open. I will update the post and jsfiddle with that addition.